# An ordered field without Archimedean Principle

Tags: analysis, axioms

The question on Zorich p.63.
d) Show that the set $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ of rational fractions
$$R_{m,n}=\frac{a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_mx^m}{b_0+b_1x+\cdots+b_nx^n}$$
with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ becomes an ordered field, but not an Archimedean ordered field, when the order relation $R_{m,n}>0$ is defined to mean $a_mb_n>0$ and the usual arithmetic operations are introduced. This means that the principle of Archimedes cannot be deduced from the other axioms for $\mathbb{R}$ without using the axiom of completeness.

It seems that I have figured out (d): the field is ordered by
$\frac{P_m(x)}{Q_k(x)} \leq \frac{P_{m^{\prime}}(x)}{Q_{k^{\prime}}(x)} 
\Leftrightarrow \frac{P_m(x)}{Q_k(x)} - \frac{P_{m^{\prime}}(x)}{Q_{k^{\prime}}(x)} \leq 0$.
And so $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} (n \geq x)$, which means it does not have Archimedean principle.

My question is about the last sentence in (d):
Why this example shows that Archimedean principle is dependent on completeness?
I think Archimedes principle only relies on the existence of maximal element in any subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$, which can be proved by defining a recursive function to find.

[image]

Comment: The sentence you have highlighted states that the Archimedean property on $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be proved from the other axioms which are used to define $\mathbb{R}$.  What are those axioms?  Where does your assertion about the integers fit into those axioms?

Comment: @XanderHenderson: I think the assertion I made about the integers are deduced from mathematical induction (MI). I think MI is seen as a self-evident principle in this boon? This book directly gives MI.

Comment: Induction comes about from the axioms for the natural numbers.  You are not working with the natural numbers here---you are working with axioms for the *real* numbers.  Where does induction come from in this setting?  And, again, what are the axioms for the real numbers which you have been given?

Comment: @XanderHenderson: I have been given axioms of addtion, multiplication, order and completeness. And you are right, only talking about $\mathbb{R}$, Archimedes cannot be deduced from other axioms. Maybe I get something ,thank you.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: but I still have some murmur about mathematical induction. As for me, I have studied logic and set theory. Isn't $\mathbb{R}$ constructed from natural number? And Archimedes is part about natural number. So I think only using Mathematical induction I can deduce Archimedes.

Comment: You *think* that you can deduce the Archimedean property from induction.  I would invite you to try.  I would then invite you to attempt that proof in the field of rational functions, and see what goes wrong.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Yeah, I have tried and failed in field of rational fractions, because the thing in one order is chaotic. But the book says in $\mathbb{R}$ the Archimedes law cannot be deduced. In $\mathbb{R}$, for a fixed $k > 0$, for all $x > 0$, we can construct a set $A = \{n \in \mathbb{N} | n k < x\}$. $A$ is wellordered, $0 \in A$, and so we can find maximal element one by one from $0$ until we find a $(n \in A) \land (n+1 \notin A)$. (In $\mathbb{R}$ we cannot find a least upper bound because it is dense.)

Comment: How do you know that $A$ is well-ordered?  What axiom of the real numbers are you using?

Comment: @XanderHenderson: YesYes, that is also my question. $A$ is well-ordered because mathematical induction is granted? (Maybe granted because the book never says it a axiom or principle but just put it. And I think expediently that $\mathbb{N}$ is more fundamental than $\mathbb{R}$ and all the subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are wellorded.)

Comment: @XanderHenderson: I think I got something. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no reason in the world to expect that $A$ is well-ordered.  Suppose that $x$ is in your field of rational functions, and not $\mathbb{R}$.  The proof obviously fails, no?

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Thx.